# WCF WebRole web.config file error

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, iis, web-config

I am trying to host a WCF REST service on Azure Cloud Services using a WCF WebRole. This is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <system.diagnostics>
      <trace>
        <listeners>
          <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
            <filter/>
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
    <!--
      For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

      The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
        <system.Web>
          <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        </system.Web>
    -->
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
      <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
        <service name="WCFServiceWebRole1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
          <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFServiceWebRole1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
        </service>
      </services>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
            <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
            <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="web">
            <webHttp/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
      <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
  </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="C5687FC88969C44D" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.9.6.0" newVersion="6.9.6.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I am getting a HTTP 500.19 Internal Server Error.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgfgV.png

So now if I want to change the target .net framework in the application pool settings in IIS manager how do I do it?

I am a beginner at this. And would be really grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [these instructions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754523%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to change the .NET framework for the application pool. If you don't know which application pool your web application is running on, follow [these instructions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725601%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to find out.

There is a way to set the framework in an automated fashion. Full disclosure, I developed a tool that does this (check my profile for more info). Otherwise, my answer above should work for you, especially if you only need to do this for one or two applications.